# If $ \displaystyle F(x) = \int_{1}^{3 x} \frac{1}{t} ~ \mathrm{d}{t} $, find $ F'(x) $.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Did I do the following correctly?

\begin{align*}
    F'(x)
& = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}{x}}
    \left[ \int_{1}^{3 x} \frac{1}{t} ~ \mathrm{d}{t} \right] \\
& = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} [\ln(3 x) - \ln(1)] \\
& = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} [\ln(3 x)] \\
& = \frac{1}{x}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, although there is no need to know the anti-derivative explicitly. Use the chain rule: $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_1^{3x} \frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d} t = \frac{1}{3 x} \frac{\mathrm{d} (3x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{x} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely correct. You can also do it the following way, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
\begin{align}
F'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \int_{1}^{3x} \frac{1}{t} \,d{t} \right] \\
      &= \frac{d}{du} \left[ \int_{1}^{u} \frac{1}{t} \,d{t} \right] \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \quad (\text{Using the substitution $ u = 3x $ and the Chain Rule.}) \\
      &= \frac{1}{u} \cdot 3 \quad (\text{By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.}) \\
      &= \frac{1}{3x} \cdot 3 \\
      &= \frac{1}{x}.
\end{align}
This method works even if you have a more complicated integrand than $ \dfrac{1}{t} $. It is what I usually show my students in my freshman calculus class after I have taught them the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your answer is indeed correct. However, you need not have performed the integral. You could resort to [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (Fundamental theorem of Calculus in disguise) for this. The rule goes as follows.
If $$F(x) =  \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt,$$ then $$F'(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \dfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} dt + f(x,b(x)) \dfrac{db(x)}{dx} - f(x,a(x)) \dfrac{da(x)}{dx}$$
In your case, $f(x,t) = \dfrac1t$, $a(x)=1$ and $b(x) = 3x$. Hence, we find that the first and last terms in the above equality are zero. The only non-zero term is the second term i.e.
$$F'(x) = f(x,b(x)) \dfrac{db(x)}{dx} = \dfrac1{3x} \times 3 = \dfrac1x$$
Leibniz integral rule is especially handy when integrating $f(x,t)$ i.e. computing $\displaystyle \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt$ explicitly is difficult.

Comment: Based on the level of the OP's question, I doubt that he/she is familiar with partial derivatives, or would know what the notation $\partial f(x,t)/\partial x$ means.

Comment: @JesseMadnick But I learn more from Marvis's answer, Marvis's answer gave me something more to read and learn about, other than the simple terminal answers mostly given here.

Comment: I stand happily corrected :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should google "Differentiation under the Integral sign".

Define a function:
$$G(x)=\int_1^x \frac {1}{t} \mathrm{d}t$$

So,
$$F(x)=G(3x) \to F'(x)=[G(3x)]'=3G'(3x)=3\cdot \frac {1}{3x}=\frac{1}{x} $$

Where I used the chain rule for differentiation, and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: +1.  You should change $G(3y)$ to $G(3x)$, however.

Comment: edited it - thx.